# Alternative to Bosch T 308 BOF for tight curve in 18 mm MDF

Tags: blade, saw-blade, jigsaw

I am fairly new to woodworking and I need to cut some hearts in 18 mm MDF - please see the design at the bottom of the post, including a revision inspired by @WhatRoughBeast. The radius of the curve is circa 30 mm and the default blade which came with my Bosch PST 650 is clearly unsuitable. I had a look at the manual - [this website](https://www.bosch-do-it.com/gb/en/diy/tools/pst-650-3165140653251-199894.jsp) contains [this direct link to the download, you may notice the link contains the extension .pdf twice but I checked and it works](https://www.bosch-do-it.de/media/garden/gardenmedia/leaflets/576152_Leaflet_PST_Compact_Tools_2012_eng-uk-17pdf..pdf). I included a snippet below anyway, it says I need a "T 308 BOF" but these are only pricey and only available online.

**My question is, what is the next best blade I can go for?**

T 101 AO and T 101 AOF are both for clean curves but only up to 15 mm. I would imagine they can still produce decent results in a slightly thicker sheet - or am I better of with T 244 D, which are in stock in my local Selco, and OK for up to 50 mm but branded "fast" as opposed to "clean"?

My budget is limited and I don't use the jigsaw that much so I don't want to buy a full pack of the wrong blades. I don't mind branded/unbranded - any suggestions would be appreciated.
[image: Blade table]
[image: Design preview]
[image: design v2]

Comment: How many is "some"? If it's a limited enough number could you envisage using a coping saw? Presumably you'd be intending to refine the outside shape anyway so if it's a bit less accurate than if cut with a jigsaw then it shouldn't be a big issue. And extending from this, for a small enough batch you could even cut the shape mostly with a hand saw (creating a faceted version of the heart shape) which you then smooth out.

Comment: Is there a reason that you're limiting yourself to Bosch brand blades?  Jigsaw blades are generally interchangeable.  (There are two shapes, "T" and "U", but most saws use the "T" shape.)

Comment: @Graphus, there are 20 of them, and they are heart shaped openings in the boards so it's not really an option but thanks anyway.

Comment: @SaSSafraS1232 it's awkward to tell you this but I did say "I don't mind branded/unbranded" in my OP.

Comment: You can drill a hole and thread a coping saw blade through it to get started on a closed interior curve, as long as its close enough to the edge.

Comment: If you don't care what brand blade you're using I'd just go to the store and buy something.  Honestly I would bet that the "15mm" blade will cut just fine through 18mm stock, just that it'll be slightly above the bottom of the material on the top of the stroke.  18mm is still less than 3/4" and pretty much every blade is going to cut through a 3/4" sheet.

Comment: Also, if you're having trouble making a curve cut just make a bunch of perpendicular relief cuts in the waste.

Comment: @SaSSafraS1232 Thanks for all your input, I really appreciate it. Please don't get me wrong, as I appreciate your rep score, but for the benefit of the woodwork stack exchange developing, shouldn't your last three comments be one answer?

Comment: While not entirely on the question you asked, I'd recommend making the points at the tops of the hearts much less sharp. Particularly in MDF, they will be extremely fragile and almost certain to break sooner or later.

Comment: @WhatRoughBeast thanks! I can easily see how your comment would get criticism on some other stack exchanges for being not on the question but I do appreciate it. 5 minutes work in CAD, I scaled the arcs around the "tangent" ends by a 1.2 factor and trimmed in the middle. This will clearly help with getting a clean cut too, win-win!

Comment: Why not use two plunges of a forstner bit and then simply jigsaw with any old blade toward the bottom point?

Comment: @AloysiusDefenestrate, that's a really good suggestion now that we know what's being cut. Two potential issues with the drilling part of the operation, the first is the size of the Forstner/sawtooth bit required (60mm, well over 2", not cheap) and whether the OP has a drill press with sufficient reach to allow it to be used for this. The latter is not fatal as a drilling jig could easily be devised, made *and* implemented, but the issues with drilling freehand using a large Forstner-style bit would be worth mentioning in your potential Answer.

Comment: @pateksan Yeah, I didn't feel really good about writing an answer that is just "you're overthinking it, just buy whatever".  It seemed like it would come across as insensitive.  I think you're right that this discussion could be pulled together into an answer now.  Also, thanks for adding the detailed design in, it really helps frame the discussion.

Comment: @SaSSafraS1232, "frame the discussion", I see now what you did there.

Answer (score 2):

Okay, (rubs hands together)... ready for an answer. I'll try to combine information from the comments (and will happily edit based on feedback if I've misconstrued anything).

To your question specifically. The T101 blades (or a similar generic) will turn tight curves because of its thin back and cut fairly cleanly. Don't worry about the supposed 15mm depth restriction -- the blade is long enough to go through 18mm. (It won't cut quite as cleanly as the fleam cut teeth of the 308, but not far off in MDF. The 308, by the way won't turn tight curves easily because of the thick back of the blade.) The T244 will be a rougher cut due to the nature of the teeth.

The bad thing about the T101 and T244 blades is that they won't track straight lines as nicely as a more typical (thicker) blade. One might want to cut curves with the thin blade and then switch.

You could also get away with using a normal 'clean for wood' blade with a thick back, and simply going back and forth to nibble up to the line. Just be sure to make enough room in the kerf that you can pivot the blade for a tight curve.

Depending on the jigsaw, blades can skew off vertical when cutting tight curves. Be sure to do a test piece and see that the front and back are lined up to your needs. If you find too much skew, then slow down and do more back and forth nibbling, rather than straight ahead cutting. (The downside to the nibbling is that it'll take more cleanup afterwards.)

Alternately, you could drill the round parts with a forstner bit (sometimes called sawtooth, though there are slight technical differences) or a holesaw.

A large forstner bit is non-cheap and ideally would be used in a drill press. Lacking a drill press, one would make a guide template with the same size hole and clamp it on your finish piece to constrain the forstner. (To make the first hole in the template, tack 3 strips of anything up against the sides of the forstner bit. The first template can be used to create an additional template that has two or four perfectly spaced holes.)

The holesaw is cheaper, though slower. Again, a drill press would be ideal, but because the holesaw has a pilot bit, it's a little easier to drill accurate holes handheld. A guide template would guarantee that you didn't skitter off and mess up your final product. Tip: clean the mdf dust off the holesaw teeth regularly... the dust clogs the gullets, which creates heat, which leads to premature dulling of the holesaw teeth. Tip 2: drill a hole in the rim of the holesaw's cutting path (inside the heart where it'll be waste) to help sawdust get knocked off the teeth.

To be very clear: using a handheld drill and either the forstner or holesaw isn't ideal. Take it slow and position yourself in a way that doesn't get your arm ripped off when the bit binds. You also need to be perfectly perpendicular.

If you go the round hole route, then cutting the straight lines down to the bottom point of the heart can be done with any old 'clean for wood' blade.

As a complete aside, if I had 20 of these to do, I'd readily justify the purchase of a router and a template setup, but I understand that not everyone is as addicted to power tools as me.

Thanks @Graphus and  @SaSSafraS1232 for comments.

Comment: The project is on hold due to repairs cropping up at home etc. Great answer but surprised to see you say 308 won't turn tight curves. Do you think even the BOF variant (as opposed to BF, see snippet in OP) would be unsuitable?

Comment: Aaah, didn't distinguish between the BF/BOF variants. The wider blade of the 308bf will always resist turning more than a narrower blade. The 308bof is slightly narrower, so would turn better.

Answer (score 1):

Bosch does have an overwhelming number of T-shank blades. I had a tough time on a similar decision. Their website isn't super helpful. So I copy/pasted all this information from different pages on their site into a single spreadsheet (and printed it out to keep w/ my saw/blades.

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1sgFrvqPYIU0z6UNRBJh4e5130Av6ub3vGhqUeVhsRK0/edit?usp=sharing

All of these blades should fit all Bosch jigsaws: the blue line (for Pros) like you have and the green line (for DIYers) like referenced in the PDF you linked.

For your specific application (curved cuts in 18 mm MDF) it seems you are right that the T308BO is the right blade. Not sure when you last looked but it seems like the orange big box store has a 5 pack for $10. I agree that's a bit expensive but you risk spend more ruining the wrong blade.

It's not an exact science but you could take a copy of the tooth profile to your local store and buy a no-name brand blade that most closely matches tooth profile, TPI, and blade thick/widthness of the Bosch one.

[image]